# How to send react app to client with express when you have routes that are authenticated and some that are not?

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt

I have a node application that serves my react app like this:

```
// STATIC ASSETS WHEN PUSHED TO HEROKU
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
});
```

normally this should be the last route you put, as it overrides all other get routes. However, I have some middleware that checks for authentication:

```
const jwt = require("express-jwt")
const auth = jwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  userProperty: 'payload'
});
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use(auth);
app.use("/api", routes);
```

The `/auth` routes are used to login and register and thus are not protected by middleware, the `/api` routes however are.

But, when I try to use the app, it does not properly send the data back from API requests such as `GET /api/users`, instead returning the HTML as specified in the * route.

Is there a way for me to have my authenticated routes and still serve my react app correctly?

Comment: Can you share your `routes` code?

Comment: did it resolve?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your HTML routes at the bottom and make only API routes use the `auth` middleware. This will not execute auth middleware for your static pages and will authorize `/api` routes only.

```
const jwt = require("express-jwt")
const auth = jwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  userProperty: 'payload'
});
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.get("/api", auth, routes);



 // STATIC ASSETS WHEN PUSHED TO HEROKU
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
});
```